# How to include posts with a theme

Tags: theme-development, import

I am making a theme and would like to submit the posts that i have made with the theme to the user. How can this be done?

Comment: Generally, theme developers include a XML file which the theme users can import. It includes all the demo content and is very easy to import. To create one, simply use the export tool and add the file to a new folder in the themes root directory. You mat also want ti link to some setup instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the posts via the exporter at `wp_admin->Tools->Export` and bundle the resulting file. Provide the end user with instructions for importing them-- basically, install the [WordPress importer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) and then visit `wp_admin->Tools->Import`.

Please do not try to force installation of your posts automatically as it will insert data into the user's database. That just isn't friendly.